# How to create multiple 'new' pages within a controller that behave the same with different text?

Tags: ruby

Ok - I have a simple application built that allows you to store action items based on business categories: Business Admin, Business Development, Business Financial, Etc.

Each one of the categories, will have the same exact form:

```
<div align="center"><h1>What are your important Business Admin Action Items?</h1>


<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
<p>

<p>Store Answer Below:</p>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :size => 40, :style => 'height: 40px' %>
</p>

<p>
<%=f.submit 'Save action item' %>
</p>
<% end %> </div>
```

However, not all of these categories will have the same H1 tag (or other text/attributes within the view). So, how does that work?

Do I create new pages, that are: business_admin.html.erb, business_development.html.erb etc - and if so, I can't see how I'd use the same new action for all of them, especially since the answers to the user input are going to be stored on separate pages (the categories' respective pages: business_admin_storage.html.erb, etc.

I understand that naming the urls in that fashion may not be the best way, nor a conventional way. That's part of my question as well. How should I approach this situation. Will be trying a whole host of stuff in the meantime :) If I need to be more clear, please tell me.

New to rails. Loving every second.

```
Categories controller

class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @categories = Category.all
end 

def new 
    @category = Category.new
end 

def create

    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    @category.save


end 

def show 
end 

def destroy
end 

private
def category_params
params.require(:category).permit(:answer)
end
end

Index View

<h1>Select A Business Category To Begin Identifying Action Items</h1>

<ol><li><%= link_to 'Business Admin', new_category_path %></li><br><br>
<li><%= link_to 'Business Development/Marketing', new_category_path %></li><br><br>
<li><%= link_to 'Financial', new_category_path %></li>
</ol>


<%= link_to 'Store random action items', new_facilitate_path %>
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :facilitates
resources :categories 
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root 'categories#index'
get 'show' => 'facilitates#show'
get 'index' => 'categories#index'
get 'business_admin' => 'categories#new'
```

SHOW

```
Stored !! 

<h1>Listing stored action items for this category... </h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your model for Categories but it seems like you're varying the page served based on the name of the category?

Wouldn't something like this cover you?

```
<div align="center">
  <h1>What are your important <%= @category.name %> Action Items?</h1>
</div>
```

You would need to pass the relevant `@category` to the relevant view via the controller, here is the Rails 4 way:

```
before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

...

def show
end

...

private
 def set_category
   @category = Category.find(params[:id])
 end
```

And your `Categories` model would need to have a `name` property defined, which if you don't have it already could be accomplished by a migration.

Comment: What needs to happen is: from localhost:3000/categories, where an index page lists the 3 business categories, you need to be able to link to individual pages that have forms for each business category (or a partial, with different text). There needs to be new html.erb pages created, I am supposing. That's what I was getting at. 

What I've done today, after asking the question is:

Create bizadmstor, bizdevstor, and bizfinstor (all .html.erb). On those pages, I have individual text for each category on the top, and a form for @ variablethatmatchescategory, a new action @variable = Category.new

Comment: Also - how does creating a name property in the model work? Currently, the model category.rb doesn't have anything in it. I think I see what you're saying, by being able to call the category name within the H1. What would be benefit over doing that than just typing it? There will be separate views anyway, I presume (at least, I don't see another way).

Comment: @Ryan If you established a has_many relationship between your categories and your action items, you can nest a form for creating new action items inside a view of the category. The created action item will be implicitly linked to the category it was created within. This will allow you to avoid the three separate views.

Comment: Ah - got it. I'll let that sink in and give it a go. So - I have to, within the category model, has_many... "method name in categories controller?" I'll definitely research further to approach how to do that. I get the concept of what you're saying. Just have to employ it now. Marked answered. Thanks a ton !! Really cool.

Comment: There are a few different ways of approaching your problem; the approach I've suggested (an `action_items` model nested underneath your `categories` model) is one that allows for more than 3 categories in the future, without further code or config modifications. I hope that's what you were aiming for, but there are definitely other ways if not. Good luck!

Comment: Can you be more specific ? - 1. I've established: Class Name in model, which belongs_to Category, which has_many :names. I have methods called: bizdev, bizfin, bizadm, each with variables = Category.name - on view, I get "what are your important Category Action items." - It simply prints the word "Category" on the view. Also - I do not know how to create an action_items model nested underneath categories. Literally 3 weeks into rails. No prior prog exp. Also - passing relevant category to relevant view? What exactly does that mean? Thx for help. Be as specific as possible.

Comment: @RyanBallow sorry for the delay, rather than try and explain everything in the comments I threw together a (very!) rough demo. https://github.com/kimgb/nestdemo

Comment: Ok, really cool. I'll get into it and try to understand what's going on here. Thanks for your answer!